# CSS Stack images from right to left, out of the DIV

Tags: css, image, css-float, whitespace, nowrap

I'm trying to achieve a past and future picture line in 2 divs. All pictures on left side of screen stack to infinity from right to left  and all images on the right side of screen stack to infinity left to right. I have almost achieved this except I can't stop the images going to a new line.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XHacq/)

HTML

```
<div id="parent1">
   <div id="past">
      <img id="topic1" src="./img/topic1.png"></img>
      <img id="topic2" src="./img/topic2.png"></img>
      ...

   </div>
   <div id="future">
      <img id="topic1a" src="./img/topic1a.png"></img>
      <img id="topic2b" src="./img/topic2b.png"></img>
      ...

   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#parent {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%
}

#future {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width:50%;
  left:50%;
  top:0%
}

#future img {
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  margin: 1%;
  max-height: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#past {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width:50%;
  left:0%;
  top:0%
}

 #past img {
  float: right;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  margin: 1%;
  max-height: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Any help would be great. Currently they're stacking vertically to infinity :(

Comment: it would be except I've used nowrap. Still not fixed the problem

Comment: Can you add a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) demonstrating your code? You could probably get rid of the floats as images are displayed inline-block, so I do not think that they are needed

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/XHacq/ 

first ever fiddle, that was fun

Comment: getting rid of the floats does put them side by side but I wanted to have the left side stack to the left and the right side stack to the right

Comment: and putting position: static in puts everything on a new line again

Comment: ok thats kind of fixed it for the future side i.e. the right, but how do I stack the past side from right to left? i've updated the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/XHacq/3/

Comment: Are you trying to achieve something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/XHacq/4/

Comment: cool. Yes almost. Except I'm disabling the overflow and moving the entire div. If you imaging the 'I' is the center of the screen I'm trying to make this:

[  ] [  ] [  ] [  ] I [  ] [  ] [  ]

Comment: also I learn more in your jfiddle than I have from all the websites I've read :p need to re write all my css now

Comment: this is almost what I want http://jsfiddle.net/8N2PM/ except I'd like the left images to stack off the screen to the left and I'll move the div afterwards. So close! If you figure it out please post it as an answer and accept it, really appreciate the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description in the comments, you would like the following structure:

```
3 - 2 - [ 1 | 1 ] - 2 - 3
```

Where the elements numbered 1 are visible and 2 & 3 are off the screen but still inline.

You could achieve this by having the elements in the div on the right - `#present` - using text direction left to right (*default in western browsers, but worth specifying if your layout depends on it*) and the div on the left - `#future` - using the text direction right to left. You can then hide the overflowing elements using `overflow: hidden` within the parent element:

**CSS**

```
img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#past, #future {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width:50%;
    left:0%;
    top:0%;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#past {
    left:50%;
    text-align: left;
    direction: ltr;
}

#future {
    text-align: right;
    direction: rtl;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="past">
    <img id="topic1" src="/path/to/image1.jpg"></img>
    <img id="topic2" src="/path/to/image2.jpg"></img>
    <img id="topic3" src="/path/to/image3.jpg"></img>
</div>
<div id="future">
    <img id="topic1a" src="/path/to/image4.jpg"></img>
    <img id="topic2b" src="/path/to/image5.jpg"></img>
</div>
```

**Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/vymvN/**

Comment: I've never seen direction: rtl before. That perfect though. Thank you very much. Do you think you could remove the "This question may already have an answer here" at the top? I feel this question hasn't been answered before. Congrats on the 10.3 k rep by the way. That's extremely impressive

Answer (score 0):

Right. The current answer I've got is to `float: right`, and make the `#past` div dynamically change width based on how many images are in it. If there is a of a non JavaScript way I'd be chuffed to learn about it :D

CSS

```
#past {
   right: 50%;
   width: 300%;
}

#past img {
   float: right;
}
```

JQuery

```
$('#past').css('width', ( $('#past > img').size() ) * 100 + "%");
```